# How to remove white screen on iPhone simulator when launching iOS App with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

So recently I bought a MacBook and wanted to deploy my App on an iPhone Emulator or my own iPhone. I have downloaded Xcode and did the complete setup. I can run the App on an Android Device with VSCode.

My Problem is when I try to deploy the App on an iPhone Emulator Xcode shows "Build Succeeded" and the launches. Unfortunately the App shows only a white Screen without any content. I also don't get any errors in Xcode to see what went wrong.

Here are some further informations like the versions I use:

- Xcode 14.2
- MacBook Air 2019 (macOS Ventura 13.0.1)
- Flutter doctor output

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-x64, locale
    de-DE)
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to
      /usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.19.0/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your
      current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/.../Desktop/dev/flutter.
      Consider adding /Users/.../Desktop/dev/flutter/bin to the front
      of your path.
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

- Output in Xcode

```
dyld[3911]: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
  Referenced from: <5DA20BAC-47DD-34B3-BBAF-653D2E87F49B> /Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: tried: '/Users/.../Desktop/dev/20230119_parkbestapp/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2)
Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
  Referenced from: <5DA20BAC-47DD-34B3-BBAF-653D2E87F49B> /Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D877DEB0-3278-4713-AF1F-26F77F87E0F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/570934F1-6DA9-4B1E-BCAC-45BD188620C7/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: tried: '/Users/.../Desktop/dev/20230119_parkbestapp/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.f
dyld config: DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/22A400/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2.20C52 DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/.../Desktop/dev/20230119_parkbestapp/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/usr/lib/libRPAC.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/.../Desktop/dev/20230119_parkbestapp/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resource
(lldb)
```

Does anyone else have a problem with launching an Flutter App on an iPhone with Xcode?

I'm grateful for every hint I get. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How exactly are you running the app? Through Xcode? Make sure to select .xcworskapce and not .xcproj.

Comment: Also, flutter doctor shows that you have two conflicting flutter installations. Did you install one of them threw homebrew? Try cleaning up your installations to only reference one

Comment: I opened .xcworkspace in Xcode and clicked on the "Play"-Button. After Build succeeded the App launches but with white Screen.

Comment: @jraufeisen do you know how I can do this? I am new to MacOS.

Comment: I suspect that the dependencies for iOS are not installed. Did you run "pod install" inside the "/ios" subdirectory? You will need Cocoapods if you don't have it yet. Another idea would be to run "flutter run" instead of running through Xcode. Then you might see more related error messages

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem before, what I did was just run "flutter run" on terminal instead of play from Xcode and it works! My App can launch as usual without any error.